# Image didn't insert properly while load image from gallery to gridview with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to load all image from gallery to activity with asynctask. I learn it from this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/09/getview-to-load-images-in-asynctask.html). But there was a problem that I was unable to solve yet.

When I scroll down slowly from the grid view it work perfectly fine. But When I scroll up or scroll faster the Image view either will load previous loaded image then only loaded the correct photo or it might loaded few photo randomly eventually only get to the correct photo.

Here is my source code

```
public class PhotoPicker extends ActionBarActivity {
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
AsyncTaskLoadFiles myAsyncTaskLoadFiles;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_picker);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();



    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

    myAsyncTaskLoadFiles = new AsyncTaskLoadFiles(myImageAdapter);
    myAsyncTaskLoadFiles.execute();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_photo_picker, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public class AsyncTaskLoadFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    ImageAdapter myTaskAdapter;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Cursor cur;


    public AsyncTaskLoadFiles(ImageAdapter adapter) {
        myTaskAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };

        // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
        Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        // Make the query.
            cur = context.getContentResolver().query(images,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"        // Ordering
        );



        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            String bucket;
            int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            do {
                bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                publishProgress(bucket);
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            } while (cur.moveToNext());

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        myTaskAdapter.add(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        /*myTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    void remove(int index){
        mArrayList.remove(index);
    }

    public void add(String path){
        mArrayList.add(path);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return mArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        int position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(230, 230));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

            convertView = imageView;

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = imageView;
            holder.position = position;
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            ((ImageView)convertView).setImageBitmap(null);
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {

            private ViewHolder v;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {

                v = params[0];
                Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(mArrayList.get(position), 220, 220);
                Log.d("holder", String.valueOf(position));
                return bm;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //Not work for me!
                v.image.setImageBitmap(result);





            }
        }.execute(holder);

        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        //return imageView;
        return convertView;

    }


}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
                                         int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return bm;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(

        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

}
```

Apologies if my english make it confuse the link that I provide have 2 youtube video the second video also have the problem that I mention earlier.Any help really very grateful

Answer (score 0):

It is because GridView (ListView, RecyclerView also) is re-using already existing views. When row view moved out of the screen GridView is re-using this view for another data.

In your example, when you call `v.image.setImageBitmap(result);` it may change image on view that is already used for another data item.

To fix this you should check if view is still related to your data model, e.g.

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    holder.image.setTag(position);
    new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if(v.image.getTag() == position) {
                v.image.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, I would have to check it more deeply to know what is going on. Maybe use Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso) - it handle very easily image downloading and setting.